# How to enable audio only when earphones are plugged in

Tags: windows-7, audio

I'm on a windows 7 laptop. Following a very embarrassing incident, I'd like to make my computer only play audio when my earphones are plugged in. If for any reason the earphones are unplugged, I'd like the computer to mute itself immeadiately, with no chance of any sounds leaking. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Sound icon in the menubar, and select "Playback devices". Depending on your sound card, headset/earphones, and driver setup, the internal speaker and the audio jack may be listed as separate devices. All you need to do is find the internal speaker, right click it, and select disable. If you do not have two separate listings, it's a bit finnicky. If you use Realtek HD Audio, you go into the control panel and check this box to separate them:

[image: Realtek HD Audio Manager screenshot]

If you have another driver, there may not be this option, but it's always worth checking.

If your driver can not make them distinct, a ghetto solution would be to pull the laptop apart and just disconnect the wire connecting the external speakers to the motherboard.

Comment: I do use Realtek HD Audio, but when I click on Device advanced settings the window only shows options for Recording Device, and not playback device. The Internal speaker and audio jack were not seperate, so I'm afraid this is my only option. Can you help me to get it work?